# Assertion for .dat reading fails

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

Here are the functions I am calling:

```
bool getPlayer(int& jerseyNumber, string& firstName, string& lastName, int& minutesPlayed){
    infile >> jerseyNumber;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> firstName;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> lastName;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> minutesPlayed;
    assert(!infile.fail());

    //set values
    return true;
}

void getShooting(int& fga, int& fgm, int& tpa, int& tpm, int& fta, int& ftm){
    infile >> fga;
    assert(!infile.fail()); //check if it failed, and abort.
    infile >> fgm;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> tpa;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> tpm;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> fta;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    infile >> ftm;
    assert(!infile.fail());
    return;
}
```

My main function is calling them in this way:

```
infile.open("lab3.dat");
fout.open("output.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    getPlayer(jersNums[i], firstNames[i], lastNames[i], totalMinutes[i]);
    getShooting(fgas[i], fgms[i], tpas[i], tpms[i], ftas[i], ftms[i]);
}
infile.close();fout.close();
```

The getShooting functions assertion fails right after the `infile >> fta;` line.
I have no idea why. The structure of lab3.dat is as follows (each number is a different data point):

```
99 George Mikan 379 179 72 0 0 81 62 58 86 0 0 19 0 42
```

This isn't necessarily the way I want to do it but this is for a computer science assignment, so I have to do it this way. Is there any obvious reason why this assertion is failing?

Comment: You have a lot more data points in the file than what you're reading in the functions you've shown.  Your function reads 10 things, but your file has 17 things to read on the line.

Comment: Yes I've just omitted the other two functions for brevity. It's failing in the second function nonetheless.